# How to automatically execute test cases of test link management tool using jenkins+ cucumber runner file

Tags: jenkins, automation, cucumber, automated-tests, testlink

Is there a way to configure Jenkins such that it takes the results obtained from Cucumber results and then updates the execution status in testlink?

- Problem 1 : As of now, I am unable to integrate Cucumber output to Jenkins.
- Problem 2 : Unable to update test link results.

Comment: Did you try https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Cucumber+Reports+Plugin?

Comment: Thanks for the response , appreciate !!as am new to this , I was unable to configure this in my code / jenkins , besides how to configure these results to Test Link ??

Comment: Jenkins result seeking strategy have the options like using j unit class name , suite name ,method name , running through cucumber , I created testng xml file for runner class and then calling that as a batch command in jenkins.